# How to filter orders for a customer API Woocommerce 2.6

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I am filter orders based on the ID of a client, following syntax doesn't working, when i try:

```
www.example.com/wp-json/wc/customers/1/orders?
```

Provide me correct syntax

i'm on woocommerce 2.6

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

try this syntax

```
get orders?customer=1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Woocommerce API version 3 (v3), use this format:

```
http://<your-domain>/wc-api/v3/orders?filter[customer_id]=<Customer Id>
```